# Replace Character Only if it isn't Immediately Preceded By Specified Character

Tags: c++, regex, regex-replace

Given a multiple line string `A;1;\nB;2\nC;3`. It's needed to add a `;` before those `newline` characters that are **not** immediately preceded by `;`. So, the result should be `A;1;\nB;2;\nC;3` (a single `;` is added after `2`). I've tried different `regex`es but without luck (one of them is presented below). I think the lookbehind assertion would do the job, but it isn't supported.

**Question:** What `regex` expression can solve this problem? If none, how to solve it using other methods using pure C++ only (I'm using `C++20`)?

```
std::string s{ "A;1;\nB;2\nC;3" };
const std::regex re("(?!;)\\n");  // Produces "A;1;;\nB;2;\nC;3" (redundant ";" after "1").
s = std::regex_replace(s, re, ";\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match and capture either a string start position or any character other than a `;` char, and then capture a newline char, and replace the matches using backreferences:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string s{ "A;1;\nB;2\nC;3" };
    const std::regex re("([^;]|^)(\\n)");  // Produces "A;1;;\nB;2;\nC;3" (redundant ";" after "1").
    s = std::regex_replace(s, re, "$1;$2");
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/tIcKQx) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jAGK0B/1).

Output:

```
A;1;
B;2;
C;3
```

*Pattern details*:

- `([^;]|^)` - Group 1 (`$1`): either a char other than a semi-colon (`[^;]`), or (`|`) a start of the string position (`^`) (remove `|^` if there is no need to match substrings at the start of the string)
- `(\\n)` - Group 2 (`$2`): a newline char.

Comment: Wiktor, thank you for your detailed explanation! Didn't know about backreferences. Will take a closer look at them.

Comment: @ENIAC See more at ["Numbered Backreferences"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html), too.

Comment: Thank you very much, Wiktor! Seems it is a great resource.